# Retrieving Data from Firebase child object in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get data from firebase within react Native Application.

Attached below is my database: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkrIf.png)

.   https://ibb.co/cEVBeb

```
QWA17SaADRdgluvVnYrXJK1AvI22
-L-uNMmDRnKTkk55KbMz
allowGPS: true  
notificationSound:  true  
phone:  "345345345345345" 
pushNotification:  true 
shareData:  true  
showAlerts:  true
```

Below is the code that I've tried and they are not working.
Can someone please guide me how can I get the nested values.

```
firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}`)
.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
const username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username) || 'Anonymous';
console.log(snapshot.val().username);
console.log(snapshot.val());
console.log(snapshot.val('username'));
console.log(snapshot.child('phone').val());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a further nest inside if your firebase structure

```
QWA17SaADRdgluvVnYrXJK1AvI22
    -L-uNMmDRnKTkk55KbMz //HERE
```

So using `snapshot.val()` wont access your child components. You should only be creating one of these codes when you make a user, and assigning the key (QWA17Sa...) as its user_id. This other code is uneccessary.

To do this, use `.set` method when creating users to your firebase, similar to below. This should avoid the creation of this seperate unwanted node in your firebase structure.

```
    const userPath = `/users/${currentUser}`;

    // Save the text and a url to the saved audio file to firebase.
    firebase.database().ref(userPath).set({
      username: foo
      stuff: foo
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got to know about this later. Thank you much really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Can try this code. For me it works

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    var json = snapshot.val();
  });
```

Comment: Yeah but it stores the value of an child object. I wanted to get the values of elements inside.
Since I was pushing objects in the firebase rather then using **.set** function, a new child id is created every time. And we will need to loop through the parent to get all elements using the key of child object.